# Runtime Error 13 in For Loop

Tags: excel, vba, declaration, runtime-error

For some reason I'm getting a 'Runtime 13' error when I execute the following code.

```
Dim N_1 As Variant

Worksheets("Trucks").Activate
Range("G9").Activate

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
Loop

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
N_1 = Range(ActiveCell, "G9")

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .comparemode = vbTextCompare
    For Each v1 In N_1
        If Not IsEmpty(v1) Then
            If Not .exists(v1) Then .Add v1, Nothing
        End If
    Next
    z1 = .keys
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range(...)` returns an object type so `Set` must be used:

`Set N_1 = Range(ActiveCell, "G9")`

---

While `Range(...)` does return an object type, assigning it to a `Variant` without using `Set` produces a 2D variant array of the cell values in the range. This works OK with the `For Each v1 in N_1` part and with the `IsEmpty(v1)` part.

Therefore, I'm not 100% sure why you got error 13 in the first place (assuming that `v1` and `z1` are also declared as `Variant`). Indeed if you use `Set` you'll also have to alter your loop which populates the dictionary to use `v1.Value` instead of just `v1`

If you are subsequently using `N_1` and expecting it to be a `Range` object then this would explain things but the code as presented above runs OK for me if everything is declared as a `Variant`:

[image: Excel screenshot showing the code from the question running without errors]

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that answer helps you. I'll explain in an edit